# Insert random noise in a V slope DEM

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, noise

With the following code I am generating a V plane with 2 different slopes, 10° and 20° respectively.

```
% /*
%  Assumptions
%  */  

% resolution [m]
res = 1;
% inclination [deg]
i1 = 10; i2 = 20;


% /*
%  DEM -> V shape  
%  */  

% pre-allocate output
testDEM = zeros(513);
% required elevation step [m]
hstep = res*tan(i1*(pi/180));
% elevation start right [m]
k = 513*(2/3)*tan(i1*(pi/180));
% coordinates
q = length(1:513*(2/3));
% initialize
nStep = 0;
for jj = 1:q
    testDEM(:,jj) = k-nStep;
    nStep = nStep + hstep;
end
% change elevation step
step = res*tan(i2*(pi/180));
% update nStep
nStep = step;
% elevation start left [m]
start = testDEM(end,q);
for jj = q+1:513
    testDEM(:,jj) = start + nStep;
    nStep = nStep + step;
end
testDEM = testDEM(1:507,1:507);

%//Plot test DEM 
f_tSlope = figure();  
set(gca,'PlotBoxAspectRatio',[1 1 1]);
surf(testDEM, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
colormap jet;
hb = colorbar('location','eastoutside');
hb.Label.String = '[m]';
hb.Label.Rotation = 0;
hb.Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'Left';
```

With the following I'm adding noise in every location

```
sigma = 1;
testDEM = testDEM + sigma*randn(size(testDEM));
```

But what I'd like instead is to add random noise in random location, not everywhere. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever used randperm?
 https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
N_locations = 100; % no. of locations to add random noise
% randomize 'N_locations' linear indecies in 'testDEM':
noise_location = randi(numel(testDEM),N_locations,1);
% add the noise:
testDEM(noise_location) = testDEM(noise_location)+sigma*randn(N_locations,1);
```

This will randomize `N_locations` random locations on the map, and apply different random noise to each of them.

If you prefer to add the *same* noise to all random locations, just write `sigma*randn`, without the parenthesis after it.

For small `N_locations` this should suffice. However, if you want to make sure you don't pick the same location twice, or `N_locations` is large, you can set `noise_location` like this:

```
noise_location = randperm(numel(testDEM),N_locations);
```

so you'll have only non-repeating values of indices in `testDEM`.

Comment: Honestly, you'd be best off just using randperm.

Comment: `randperm` is a slower, so if this is going to be applied many times for a small number of locations, then `randi` may be enough.

Comment: Fair enough, for the things I do, creating random variables is less than .01% of the total processing time so I usually don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

This code adds noise with 0.5 probability

```
testDEM = testDEM + sigma*randn(size(testDEM)) .* (rand(size(testDEM)) > 0.5);
```